# Concept behind the execution of this code?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Executing this command is getting me an infinite loop also in the while condition I wrote i=30 instead of i<=30  wanna know what does i=30 does to my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  
  int i=30;//initialization
  
  while (i =30)
  {
      cout<< i<< ' '; 
      i=i+1;
  } 
 
    
}
```

Comment: It assigns 30 to I inside the loops condition

Comment: See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Comment: The 11th commandment: **THOUGH SHALT HEED THY WARNINGS!** Or else.

Answer (score 0):

`while (i = 30)` assigns the value 30 to the variable `i`, and then uses the resulting `i` as a condition. Since `i` is non-zero, it is considered `true`, and the loops runs forever.

As such, the `cout` will always print `30` and the increment of `i` will be undone at every iteration.

Comment: also whatever value  i assign  to while initializing it runs infinite loop of 30 only what can be the reason..?

Comment: @TejasAditya like Jeffrey said, `while (i = 30)` is assigning 30 to `i`, so it doesn't matter what initial value you set `i` to, it is being overwritten on every iteration. You need to use `==` (equality comparison), not `=` (assignment), eg: `while (i == 30)`